# Requisição Ajax em Formularios

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, front-end

Fiz uma requisição ajax para enviar os dados de um formulário para o servidor, os dados são enviados e armazenados perfeitamente. Porém ao tratar o **success**
criando a condição, caso o retorno do **result** fosse o padrão **200** ou **"OK"** iria emitir uma mensagem de sucesso e se não, a de erro. Porém, ao fazer isso percebi que o result não estava retornando pois já caia direto no else. E mesmo caindo ELSE, ele armazena os dados no servidor, porém lança a mensagem de erro.

```
function showMessageError(message)
    {
      document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = message;
      $("#divError").fadeIn(200).delay(2500).fadeOut(200);
    }
```

>

```
function sendForm()
{

  $("#divSucesso").hide();
  $("#divError").hide();

  document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = true;
  var formAgenda = document.getElementById("form");
  var formData = new FormData (formAgenda);

  $.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  method: "POST",
  data: formData,             
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,

  success: function (result) {

      if (result.statusText == "OK")
      {
        document.getElementById("sucessoMsg").innerHTML = "Dados salvos com sucesso: " + result;
        $("#divSucesso").stop().fadeIn(200).delay(2500).fadeOut(200);
        document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
      }
      else
        showMessageError(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {                
      var errorMsg = xhr.responseText;
      document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = errorMsg;
      $("#divError").fadeIn(200).delay(2500).fadeOut(300);
      document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = false;
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: Gabriel, poderia passar o erro que está acontecendo? Assim tenho um parâmetro pra investigar.

Comment: @MateusSaggin ai que está cara. Ele não está indicando qual é o erro, estou sem entender.

Comment: @MateusSaggin, meio que ele não está entrando no IF, por isso nao da

Comment: tem algum link rodando esse script?

Comment: @MateusSaggin, reestruturei minha pergunta, talvez fique mais claro um pouco. E te respondendo, estou testando no WAMP localmente.

Comment: Poderia postar o código do insert.php?

Answer (score 0):

Fala @Gabriel,

Agora entendi a sua pergunta, eu alteraria o código pra tratar o `200` e não o `OK`. Segue exemplo:

```
function sendForm() {

    $("#divSucesso").hide();
    $("#divError").hide();

    document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = true;
    var formAgenda = document.getElementById("form");
    var formData = new FormData(formAgenda);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {

            if (xhr.status === '200') {
                document.getElementById("sucessoMsg").innerHTML = "Dados salvos com sucesso: " + textStatus;
                $("#divSucesso").stop().fadeIn(200).delay(2500).fadeOut(200);
                document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("form").reset();
            } else {
                showMessageError(textStatus);
            }

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var errorMsg = xhr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = errorMsg;
            $("#divError").fadeIn(200).delay(2500).fadeOut(300);
            document.getElementById("btnEnviarForm").disabled = false;
        }

    })
}
```

Mas caso queira tratar o retorno do seu servidor, é possível também. É só dar um `console.log(result)`, utilizando o código que enviou e verificar se realmente está sendo retornado `OK` no atributo `result.statusText`